# Email alert for new bounty questions of specified tags

Tags: feature-request, bounties, email-notification

Is there a way to get instant email notifications when a bounty is started on any questions (of specified tags)?

Comment: If you look at featured tab for question in some tag - such as, for example, [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request?sort=featured), you can see a [RSS feed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=feature-request&sort=featured) there. If you can somehow get an email from the RSS feed, this should be a possible workaround.

Comment: adding to @Martin's comment -- something like this maybe? https://blogtrottr.com